# Accessing localhost:8000 using cntlm

Tags: laravel, proxy

I trying to access localhost behind cntlm proxy it is work for localhost but not work for localhost:8000 (I use it for laravel built in web server)

```
curl localhost
```

line above work perfectly , but when I uses port 8000 cntl give "502 Connection refused"

```
curl localhost:8000
```

and here is the result :

```
<html><body><h1>502 Connection refused</h1><p><a href='http://cntlm.sf.net/'>Cntlm</a> proxy failed to complete the request.</p></body></html>
```

here is my cntlm.conf

```
....
NoProxy         localhost,localhost:8080, 127.0.0.*, 10.*, 192.168.*, 172.19.14.*
```

could somebody please tell me how to make cntlm proxy ignore my localhost:8000 just like it ignore localhost ?

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried setting it to NoProxy?

```
NoProxy         localhost,localhost:8080,localhost:8000, 127.0.0.*, 10.*, 192.168.*, 172.19.14.*
```